# Changing an image based on text input field

Tags: jquery, html

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I cannot figure out what. All I'm doing is changing the image based on what number a user enters in the input text field. One image for 0, one image for 1, and one image for any other number. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Items in cart:</p>
    <form id="cartform">
        <input type="text" name="amt">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <img id="cart" src="cartempty.jpg" />
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cartform").submit(function() {
                var howmany = $("input[name='amt']").val();
                if (howmany == 1) {
                    $("#cart").attr("src", "cart1.png");
                } else if (howmany == 2) {
                    $("#cart").attr("src", "cart2.png");
                } else {
                    $("#cart").attr("src", "cartempty.png");
                }
            }
        });
```

Here it is: http://codepen.io/kaisle/pen/BKrfL

Thank you!

Comment: have you included the javascript library in the document?

Comment: You seem to be missing a `)` on the submit function, as well as not preventing the form from submitting and reloading the page.

Comment: The jquery library is included in my Codepn link, where I'm working on it. Thanks for all the help guys, I have clicked the checkmark for @dave's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `submit` action which is reloading the page after your javascript runs.  You need to `preventDefault()` on the submit event. See below or updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woalL).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cartform").on("submit", function(e) {
    var howmany = $("input[name='amt']").val();
    if (howmany == 1) {
     $("#cart").attr("src","http://s29.postimg.org/3t9we474j/cart1.png")
    } else {
     $("#cart").attr("src","http://s29.postimg.org/3t9we474j/cart2.png")
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Items in cart:</p>
  <form id="cartform">
        <input type="text" name="amt"><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <br/><br/>
  <img id="cart" src="http://s18.postimg.org/wn2lejomt/cartempty.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing `});` at the end of the document.ready function.
2. There's an extra `}` in the if else condition. Remove that.
3. You need to add `e.preventDefault();`
4. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` this must be added in `<head>` section of the document for enabling jquery library to function on the page.

Try the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cartform").on("submit", function(e) {
   var howmany = $("input[name='amt']").val();
   if (howmany == 1) {
     $("#cart").attr("src","http://s29.postimg.org/3t9we474j/cart1.png")
  } else {
    $("#cart").attr("src","http://s29.postimg.org/3t9we474j/cart2.png")
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: No need to highlight the entire post... please use bold only for the most important parts, not the entire post...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a form and submit for changing an image. Use a simple function that works on the onclick event.

```
<div>
  <p>Items in cart:</p>

        <input type="text" />
        <input id="theButton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeImage();"/>

  <br/><br/>
  <img id="cart" src="http://s18.postimg.org/wn2lejomt/cartempty.png"/>
</div>
```

And:

```
function changeImage()
{
    var howmany = $("input[name='amt']").val();
    $("#cart").attr("src","http://s29.postimg.org/3t9we474j/cart" + howmany + ".png");
}
```

Check: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdeqj